# Docusign Demo - One or both of Username and Password are invalid

Tags: python, rest, docusignapi

I have followed multiple threads but unable to resolve the issue. With the following endpoint:

> `https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/login_information`

getting 200 and accountId, but when I try to `POST` with following:

> `/restapi/v2/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes`

I get the following error:

> 401 - One or both of Username and Password are invalid

Answer (score 0):

You need to obtain a valid access token using OAuth either [Auth Code Grant](https://developers.docusign.com/platform/auth/authcode/), or [JWT](https://developers.docusign.com/platform/auth/jwt/). You are either attempting to use an expired token, no token at all, or you are using an older authentication mechanism no longer supported. Please use official documentation by DocuSign.

Note these URLs are for old v2 API, need to use v2.1 API

Recommend you try the Python [Quickstart](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/quickstart/) as it configures all you need to make API calls for you.

Comment: is v2 API completely deprecated?. This `/v2/login_information` endpoint works perfectly fine.

Comment: It's not deprecated, but if you're working on a brand new app - we recommend you use v2.1.

Comment: then that's not the answer I was looking for, my integrated app is implemented in `/v2` from last year suddenly it stopped working throwing **401**, I wanted to know the reason behind this because I don't see any notification of deprecation for this month.

Comment: So, to confirm. You didn't change any code or configuration, you are using the integration the exact same way as before. It was working one day and doing exactly the same action the next day is not working?

Comment: Is the issue both on the developer environment as well as production (examples you provide are from dev)

Comment: If you had a previously working integration with Legacy Authentication that suddenly stopped, please open a case with support.docusign.com and include your integration key. For new integrations, legacy auth is blocked and the `login_information` endpoint should not be used.